How to fight effectively on a space station
So the question here is fairly simple. What kind of weapons can you use on a space station that can kill someone in advanced body armor, and even the occasional person in powered armor, without too much risk of poking (too many) holes in the station itself? Depressurizing the entire station while taking it is not preferable, although a few small holes are probably fine. But how would you penetrate body armor, to actual power armor with the durability of a light armored vehicle, without having those same rounds that miss going straight through the skin of the station?
EDIT: This is different from the recoil weapons question since that question is asking about recoilless firearms, but this one doesn't care about that and is asking about ways to not poke holes in a station you are fighting on(Not necessarily zero, but as few as possible). This is important because civilian stations can have thousands of non-combatants aboard who would prefer to not breath vacuum or get shot with a stray bullet that went through the walls. The goal is to minimize civilian casualties. This question applies to weapons both the attackers and defenders can use.
Clarifications: This is focused on military action, although suggestions on how policing might work are welcome. The station has artificial centrifugal gravity. It spins and makes artificial gravity. They range from the size of small outposts to orbital cities. The station is not necessarily more armored than the body armor of the soldiers, for the same reason most buildings aren't bulletproof. Some might be armored, but most aren't. Also, this may be a civilian station, so it is preferable to not implement measures that could negatively impact other spaces in the station(Gassing a room is fine, but gassing the whole station is not. This means that things like disabling life support across the whole station is a war crime and not allowed).
The weapons technology is mostly kinetics, basically spoofed-up rifles and pistols. The station is large, enough so that Light powered armor is sometimes feasible(nothing too big). Also, the armor itself varies from just standard modern body armor like we have today, to 2 cm of armor plate. Said powered armor is uncommon, so not every weapon needs to be able to penetrate it. It is fully enclosed but with a limited air supply(~30 min). Finally, tiny drones are possible.

You're going to need to describe the physical characteristics of your body armor, powered armor, and space station pressure structures for this question to be at all answerable. What is possible with the weapons technology in your world? Without knowing these facts it is impossible for us to answer this question with anything other than us filling in the details of your world for you instead of helping you solve your specific worldbuilding problem.

Aim very carefully? Don't miss.

VTC:Needs More Details as we know nothing at all about your space station, "advanced body armor" (whatever that is) or powered armor. However, Frame Challenge: you have that armor but can't/won't armor your space station? That's a technology dichotomy. Finally, consider What kinds of weapons produce little or no recoil that could be used aboard a spacestation? which is so close to a practical duplicate that I almost voted to close this Q as a duplicate of that Q.

Food for thought: Decades ago in a copy of Dragon Magazine a cartoonist spoofed a basic truth - what's the difference between a wizard with a Wand of Lightning and a soldier with an energy weapon? Nothing. Both concepts are just window dressing for the story. Some people might get woozy over scientific detail, but that's just another form of window dressing. And your futuristic armor has more in common with magic than with science. (*Continued*)

... The basic truth you must work with is that the space station's walls are more armored than the soldier's armor because, by definition, if the station's walls are less armored than the soldiers then anything that can get through the armor will go through the station's walls. What are your options? The station walls are so thick that the penetrating object must lose momentum before piercing the outer hull or the soldiers' armor must have a weakness that can be exploited by something that won't pierce the station walls.

Have a look at what urban areas in the real world look like after there has been serious fighting - unfortunately there are plenty of choices on the news at the moment.  Unless the enemy are grossly negligent on their security so you can hack their armour, or rig their oxygen supply with anaesthetic etc, there is no way to have a non-destructive fight with modern or futuristic weapons against armoured targets.

If you didn't carefully read through the answers to the recoil question - you made a huge mistake. Your situation has all the same problems that one does unless you claim to have artificial gravity, in which case my frame challenge applies in spades.

@JBH I have edited the question to include that the station has centrifugal gravity, but I don't think it has the same issues as the recoil question, as most of the answers to that question involve better recoil management(rocket-propelled projectiles, separate weapons, etc). These are great for reduced recoil, but not for avoiding collateral damage to the station.

Why would powered suits haver armor? we don't armor forklifts.

@John Its military power armor. Common sci-fi concept.

My mistake I thought you asking about how a police force would deal with them. If its another military then they are past caring about civilian casualties. its like once you start firing missles into a small town. Colateral damage to your target is a minimal concern. by that point civilians are either in shelters, evacuated or combatants.

@John Not really. The goal is still to generally limit casualties, which is why nations generally don't carpet bomb housing blocks. There will be some collateral damage(that's just how war is), the goal is still going to be to minimize that as much as possible, at least until one side starts committing war crimes.

except the carpet bombing housing blocks is not prevented when you have tanks and missle carriers in the housing block. Once military power armor is present the risk to civilians is no longer a priority because the civilians are already at equal risk by the power armors continued presence.

@John Smart bombs and artillery, yes.  Carpet bombs, no.  Carpet bombing of cities, towns, villages, or other areas containing a concentration of protected civilians has been considered a war crime since 1977, through Article 51 of Protocol I of the Geneva Conventions.

Also "Why would powered suits haver armor? we don't armor forklifts. " <- because this is the whole reason world militaries have been researching powered suits for the past several decades.  Current material limitations make it such that full body Level IV armor would weigh about 200lb.  This is more than a human can carry, but with a powered suit, you could armor a soldier against nearly all small arms in use today.

@Nosajimiki you missed my followup, I was mistaken in thinking the question was about civilian not military conflict.

@John Ah, that makes since.

Self-Sealing Flechette.
The thin, dart-like high-velocity projectiles with super hardened tips will punch through anything; armor, flesh, equipment and station alike. One won't do a huge amount of damage to a person - much like being hit by a stray miss at a dart-board. It'll produce a yelp of pain, a heated conversation, then a conciliatory round of beer.
5 or 6 of them through a limb will immobilize it, 25 of them will incapacitate the toughest marine. A single lucky shot through the heart or brain-stem will kill.
So, what use is that then if it pierces the station too?
The capsule that fires the dart also fires a small lump of self-expanding foam, that acts like a sealant, tough and flexible. On armor it'll pinpoint where someone was hit, on a station-wall it'll create a seal over the hole, some will get pushed through by the pressure differential, and fix on the hole in the layers below. The vacuum causes it to outgas and "dry", much like any solvent-based glue.
For indirect hits to the station through ricochet or miss, ones that pass through a military target first, such that the sealant gets stopped by the armor - the hole is small enough (perhaps 3mm) that the rate of gas-escape is slow. This gives time for repair-bots to fix the hull at their leisure (when there's no more fighting).
Dart-Doping:
For extra effect, have them release a paralyzing compound on entry, a nerve-toxin that numbs and immobilizes the local flesh, muscle and all - or go the other way, causes severe pain on entry like a bullet-ant sting ("waves of burning, throbbing, all-consuming pain that continues unabated for up to 24 hours").

If the dart can deliver sealant foam, then it is already extremely deadly to humans. If it can be designed that the dart punches through armor, into a person, and releases the foam inside their body....that for one turns a tiny wound into an expanding tumor of foam, but also gluts their arteries with expanding glue, which, if it reaches the heart, the brain, or just a major artery, pretty much ends the person.
One extra option is to make the foam glue extra reactive, so that it could bond with just about any material from plastic to teflon... and thus human tissues as well.

Very good answer.. i had upgraded those flechettes to knife-missiles and also mentioned that the foam is not structural. So if you fire a circle of these things into a wall, you still get a trap door to blow-out space.

I agree with the answer in concept; a 3mm hole would indeed be "not that bad" as I've found some other stacks talking about this (https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/55993/what-size-hole-in-the-international-space-station-would-be-catastrophic).

@GoingDurden Nice idea, makes them more deadly in fewer number.

@Pica Missiles? As in explosive? Sounds great, but I've no idea how to A) make it explode on impact accurately. B) miniaturize that.  Happy to assume that might be possible in the OP's world though.

@controlgroup I'd indeed read something related about chewing-gum and holes in the international space-station - bizarre I know, but informative.

It's terrifying that that's even a thing that was considered - repairing catastrophic damage to the most advanced piece of engineering and architecture and science ever constructed with chewed gum - but yeah, for small holes, the actual force sucking air out is small so it'd probably work in a pinch.

@Escapeddentalpatient.I was more orientated towards the knife missiles of the culture, but lowtech.. https://lucray.artstation.com/projects/dOk3qW

They capture the imagination, don't they. @Pica

except foam and vacume do not mix, it should blow itself clear before it can harden. If it can outgas its not airtight nor will it stay even functionally air tight long enough to harden. It will certainly be better than nothing but it will not be air tight.

Why risk our guys at all? A space station is a hostile environment life-support system. All we need to do is reversibly break the life-support system and we win for free.

Turn up the heat.
1: Wrap the radiators in a big space blanket.
2: Position a big mirror on the dark side of the station to reflect sunlight at it.
3: Wait for the enemy to surrender or die of heatstroke.

Turn down the heat.
1: Disable their power source.
2: Block the sun. (2 for the price of 1 if they're solar powered!)
3: Wait for the enemy to surrender or freeze to death.

Steal all the air.
1: Little hole. Big pump.
2: Wait for the enemy to surrender or die of hypoxia in their space suits.
3: Pump the air back in.

I like the ideas(and will probably use them), but won't this be a war crime if the station is civilian in nature?

@Bubbles If the mission is hostage rescue, that's different, but if there are lots of armed men with body armor and machine guns willing to resist us with force on the target, no, it wouldn't be a war crime by any modern or predictable future standards, even if there are civilians onboard. And the previous intended use of the building doesn't matter: today it's a position occupied by enemy combatants.

To clarify, this is like a small orbital city. You cant just turn off the life support for a civilian space station in a war for the same reason you can't gas an important industrial center of your opponent. It's a war crime, and killing civilians is generally frowned upon. Yes, there is a garrison defending the station, no this does not make it acceptable to kill thousands of civilians.

@Bubbles Honestly that changes the question so much that I think you should make a whole different question for it: 'how do you fight men armored like APCs in a city-sized space habitat' is a very different question from 'how do you fight armored men in a tin can in space'. It would help if you also specify that both sides have the same doctrine, so we don't need to worry about the question being moot because the enemy gets a vote and a few dozen anti-tank cannons to vote with.

@Bubbles If you're worried about small arms, don't be. I assume this space city is spun up for gravity? It's practically impossible to build a city-sized structure that can support its own weight against gravity that small arms can significantly damage in the first place.

@g s Noted, thanks! I honestly thought it wouldn't be that different. And fair point with the gravity, I'll probably use that, thanks.

A space station of that size would have multiple depressurization failsafes. Auto-sealing bulkheads, for example. It could easily tolerate a few holes, especially if they’re focused on one section, without substantial collateral damage. I’d focus on shooting the bad guys first; The engineers can patch up the holes later.

“killing civilians is generally frowned upon” is unfortunately not as true as it should be. Every war causes civilian casualties, even if neither army is intentionally targeting them. In a realistic setting the attacking army would probably start shooting and trust the station’s failsafes and backup systems to mitigate collateral damage. If they’re really nice they’ll send medical & engineering teams in afterwards to provide aid. Or a neutral third party organization would handle that.

@gs Actually, civilians might matter.  The hot-questions list just happened to throw this question about using nuclear weapons at me.  Apparently use of an "indiscriminate" weapon means you can be liable for war crimes.  I think depressurizing a space station counts as indiscriminate.  ... Not that I ever thought I'd find a reason to cross over Worldbuilding.SE and Law.SE...

@CortAmmon this answer and the comment were written before the space station was described as city-like.

The same way you would fight elsewhere
A bit of a frame challenge. You have a giant space station. Not a tin-cans we use today, but a proper space station. With thousands of people living there. And rotating gravity.
Such a space station is definitely not a tin-can. You need a certain tensile strength if you want a space station to not fall apparty because of rotation. Which means you cannot have thin walls. Interior ones, sure. But exterior? And the backbone of the station? Those would need to be far stronger. So you wouldn't be able to cause a hull-breach from small arms fire. And even if you somehow could breach it, that wouldn't cause much damage. You won't lose all that much air from a hole made by a gun. You have a lot of it, since you house thousands of people on board.
An analogy of fighting on a space station would be a fight on a aircraft carrier. It's not that easy to cause a hull-breach on it. And it should be impossible to achieve it by guns. And even if you magically made some holes, that still wouldn't sink that ship.
As for the argument about material being a premium in space some people have mentioned: if you have a capacity to build a space station that can house thousands you either have extremely cheap launch options (orbital rings perhaps?) or extensive off-world infrastructure (asteorid mining for example).
So to answer your question: you fight normaly. Not that in a military campaign one would expect much fighting on space stations. Terrorist attacks, mutinies, heist - yes. Military actions - no. It should be easy to defend a space station from boarding action, and even easier to just destroy it outright. To try to take it over would be just like trying to invade an aircraft carrier mentioned earlier. Sure, it is theoretically possible. But higly unlikely.

I mostly agree with this answer, but the boarding thing, not so much.  Yes, an aircraft carrier is very unlikely to get boarded, as is a MILITARY space station, but aircraft carrier sized cargo ships are frequently attacked by pirates.  If this is by in large a civilian space station which happens to have a police, militia, or private security force to protect it, then boarding becomes a much more reasonable expectation.

@Nosajimiki They are attacked by pirates but very rarely by boarding. In the last few big cases the "pirates" (well, they were military) used warships to threaten the tanker into surrendering. Which could happen to space station. But boarding is rare. Tankers that go near dangerous shores are armed with anti-personel weapons. The only reason they don't also have anti-ship weapons is that those are illegal in ports/national waters. So huge space stations should be armed, especially if they have security force to protect it. They would protect it by using anti-ship weapons

That is actually not very common.  The vast majority of piracy done over the past few decades has been by small motor boats that board the ship by scaling the side, or even in some rare cases they land on it by helicopter https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cck_SycVb1w .  If you have the resources to own a proper warship, you are not poor enough to need to engage in piracy.

You fight like normal and patch things up afterwards.
A bullet is not going to create a hole that that loses critical amounts of air during a the time frame of a normal fight. you are talking about a very small hole and liekly less than 15PSI diffrence in pressure.  A space station has to deal with micrometriotites so the walls may even be too tough for the bulllet to pucture.
Shooting civilians is a bigger concern than shooting holes in the wall. So you fight like normal forces trying to minimize civilian casualties. try not to shoot civilians patch things up afterwards. The unique thing is the special task force that goes out as soon as fighting is done and starts finding and patching damage. Or they leave it ot hte space station crew to do it, better to drain the enemies resources. You can even imagine a game of chicken ver who will blink first and save civilians.
Now I would assume the choice to use weapon that can make holes in the hull is only going to happen when absolutly nessisary. Equivilent to using missle platforms or similiar forces on earth. I would not expect everyday soldiers to be carrying around weapons that can do this. Most of the time they only need to take down soft targets. this is like when you start rolling tanks and artillery into a city, civilian casualties are a low priority at this point.

The problem here is that real urban conflicts can last for months where there exists large no-mans-land  areas where neither side is able to meaningfully advance and repair crews will be unable to reach.

@Nosajimiki and at that point avoiding civilian casualties are not a priority. even on a planet such conflicts get huge civilian casualties from lack of water, medicine, ect.

It's not just civilians who will die if the air runs out.  Portable air tanks can work fine as a short term solution for ground troops, but once the atmosphere vents, the logistics of fighting over the station gets WAY more complicated.  If you know for a fact that you have the logistical advantage, then it makes since, but in most cases, you do not know what side has more supplies/access to supplies; so, it's better to  build a military doctrine that ensures your own supplies more than one that deprives your enemy.

@Nosajimiki except logistical knowledge is going ot be much easier to get since stealth is impossible in space, and space stations have very limited points of ingress.  whomever controls the air supply could cut it off intentionally if they know the enemy is lacking in space suits.  you unintentionally make it seem like doing this intentionally poses a huge advantage tactically. It is similiar ot hydraulic warfare.

People really need to stop saying stealth is impossible in space like it is universally true for every setting.  Stealth is impossible at the distances that stealth is possible inside of an atmosphere, yes, but space is WAY bigger than that and spaceship are WAY faster than a fighter jet. Most scifi settings actually deal with distances so large and speeds so high that they have to handwave how they can see anyone at all.

Yes, I agree that the army with control of the air can cut it off, but a tactical decision has to be made before the fighting starts "what weapons do I buy for my boarding/security teams?"  If you give everyone super armor busting railguns, and find yourself fighting an enemy who has the larger reserve of air tanks (which will usually be an unknowable variable), then your weapons become a liability.  What the OP is asking is what do you arm yourself with to avoid this whole problem, not what specific situations might come up to get around it.

@Nosajimiki no they really don't need to handwave it, any spacefaring civilization is watching space like a hawk or stuff is getting destroyed all the time. space is very big but large engine powered moving things are REALLY easy to see in space. Stealth is impossible for the same reason sneaking a running flamethrower  through a cround on a dark night is impossible.

Yeah, a flame thrower at night would be hard to miss in a crowd, but my whole point is that you are not in a crowd at all.  If some guy were standing 100km away with a flamethrower, would you see it? No.  It's too far away to see no matter how bright it is because even bright things can not be seen if they are too far away for how big and bright they are.

Stealth is a measure of how far away you can be detected, not IF you can be detected.  Stealth in space could be the difference between a detection range of 10,000km and 1,000,000km on Earth scales of distance, neither of those are stealthy, but for an interstellar civilization 1,000,000km is practically right next to you.

@Nosajimiki except it is a space station, a single location with frequent traffic, it will be well watch like airspace around an airport on earth. If you appraoch the station you will be seen.

Well watched does not mean seen far in advance.  Yes, the airspace around and airport is well watched; so, they can see planes and missiles coming from many km around... but  the time it takes a potential threat, to cross that distance is measured in minutes, if not seconds.  If you assume a similar threat profile for a space station, it means neither side knows for sure what or how far out the other-side's reinforcements are.  Control of airspace now does not mean that an enemy fleet won't show up in 10 minutes, break the blockade, and be able to provide O2 to their own ground troops.

no they would see them a long distance out, you have to match speed to dock with a station, you can't just do a flyby.

If troops are already landed, it probably means the station no longer has external weapon systems to protect itself... but that's beside the point.  This is not actually a matter of if you can stop reinforcements, but if you should arm yourself with weapons that you know will cut the air.  The problem is you are thinking tactically, but arming yourself appropriately is a strategic decision that has to be made months or years before the battle starts; so, you can't make assumptions that venting the air will be to your advantage, if you don't yet know exactly who or what you will be up against.

Foam Guns
Globs of Neodyte Premium Bonder®, mixed in certain proportions with various other chemicals results in an air-drying foam. Just like flamethrowers, you can put the diluted Neodyte Premium Bonder® in one tank and then the chemical cocktail in the other tank. Then your space marines can go and hose down anyone suspected to be an insurgent. They can’t go anywhere, and if it’s a civilian, they’re not dead
Pros:

No harm to the station, or risk of civilians being shot through walls
Civilians hit by stray fire won’t die
Allows for capture of targets
By spraying walls/roofs/floors, you can build up some cover to hide behind
If your terrorist use normal guns and pop a hole in the wall, there could be some sort of mini-foam gun mounted to the wrist (Like a hand flamer from Warhammer 40k) and that could be used to quickly fill holes on the space station.
Practical, non-military uses exist for this Foam gun

Cons:

Be a pain to clean up (Unless Neodyte® has some sort of solvent that will undo it, but then you risk your terrorists carrying some of that)
If you want the terrorists dead, you will need a secondary weapon or an alternative way of doing that
Could be obtained by your terrorists if they buy it for some of the practical, non-military uses, but then funnel it into a Foam Gun
could result in respiratory problems if inhaled or suffocation if sprayed over the mouth (although this could be a deliberate strategy to silently kill enemy operatives, spray over their mouth/nose and then drag them away



Smart fuzes
Take a handheld grenade launcher, fit it with a computerized sight and laser rangefinder, and program the grenades to explode only if they did hit a target at the expected point of their flightpath. If they miss, the fuze goes inert or it self-destructs.
On the plus side, this technology also allows "barricade-penetrating" fuzing.
FPS drones
Arguably a variant of the above, put your warhead into a drone and have a pilot (or computer) fly the warhead into the target.
Smart triggers
Instead of upgrading the projectile, modify the computerized sight and trigger so that it can only fire if there is a valid target in the crosshairs. This depends on good image recognition and short flight times, but lines of fire inside a station should be short.


Energy Weapons
Depending on the sort of tech you are dealing with in your universe, energy weapons are a good way to go. Personally, I normally shy away from energy weapons as they are almost entirely handwavium, but this is one of the few logic loopholes that really might work in your favor. Since you can define a lot of aspects of how your energy weaponry works, its easier to use this as a very solid reasoning as to why energy weapons might be more widely used over kinetics.
One of the biggest real hurdles in space travel is temperature control, and real world laser weapons are essentially insanely precise heat guns. A space station is designed specifically to be constantly radiating the heat generated by all the components and occupants of the station, usually by means of actual radiators. A suite of power armor however, likely doesn't have much ability to radiate excess heat pasta certain point.
Thus, a weapon designed to heat a surface it comes in contact with would be more effective as a means to essentially cook the occupant of the armor, without severely damaging the armor or surroundings except for possible warping or scorch marks. This also is a fairly solid reason as to why so many spacecraft and space suits/armor are all white or mirror polished, because it would reflect the widest range of the visible light radiation and likely has a degree of reflection against radiation outside the visible spectrum.

why not make the armor mirrored then?

@GoingDurden That was answered here: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/54073/does-mirror-armour-work-against-laser-guns

First of all: Air seals
Air seals, that can divide the station in very small chunks, would reduce the danger of hull breaches from "everyone dies" to "a handfull of people die".
Melee
If you go in close combat and hit your enemy with a (high tech) stick, the risk of accidental hull breaches are very low. This would also give nice story hooks. A raiding party that is not specifically interested in keeping the population alive and the station intact, could use ranged weapons and be at a considerable advantage against the defenders. For power armor wearing enemies you sent your own power armors in to brawl them.
Blunt projectiles
A blunt projectile to the head of even a well armored soldier can cause deadly trauma. Our brain (and neck) are very fragile when it comes to concussions. A mighty blunt blow with a heavy rubber projectile can make an enemy unconcious or outright kill them depending on energy, angle of impact and distance. Yes you can reinforce the neck against braking but at the cost of head movability. But you can't protect the brain against the effects of sudden movement. But the bulkhead will only get dents. Not pretty but safe.
Electricity
Electricity can kill a soldier and cause malfunction in powersuits, but the hull gets only a little warm at worst and quickly dissipates the electricity and heat. Yes you might fry the cable works in the wall but at least you won't have a hullbreach.
Yes the body armor might be non conductive but with enough voltage you can get any material to conduct. If it doesn't conduct you aren't using enough voltage.
Also you might use small projectiles to pierce the armor and deliver the charge directly. Yes those small projectiles can pierce the bulkhead but at least it's only a small hole.
Last but not least: Smart weapons
The weapon calculates the distance to the target on the fly and combusts the round a few centimeters after supposed impact. Even if you miss, the projectile won't hit the bulkhead. Alternatively the weapons have a full detailed map of the station and all bulkheads and detonate the projectiles shortly before they hit the wall.
This could make interesting stories as you can have an arc about aquiring the scans of the station before the assault. Or the hero having his "smart module" damaged and now be very careful to not break the hull, while his enemies can fire at will.

You watch the "ringing" of the station.. as in every time somebody moves about the station, impacting the wall, it changes the rotation, movement of the whole station, measurably. And if leaves heat marks in the walls.
Then you mercilessly drone sniper through the tin-can walls. As this turns the holes into thrusters, you want the space-station empty beforehand, so you need to hacker-hijack the station and evaccum-ate the whole thing ahead of time.
So, if you want a sonar picture of the whole thing, you will need to get that first. Attach drones outside, ring the whole thing like a bell. Map the acoustics. Again, if anything seems like a enemy in the metal-space-shack, blast it through the corrugated roof. Drones will patch the swiss cheese later.
If some part makes more trouble then its worth- laser cut the whole affair into two parts. Again, its a coke-can in space. Not worth loosing life and limb to stumble around in it.

Cool idea, but does not meet the requirement of "not poking a lot of wholes in the space station"

some options:

first, a minor Frame Challenge: a space station is unlikely to have very heavy powered armor. Space is at premium at a station/spaceship, and every gram of weight had to be dragged out from a gravity well, or created in space from asteroid mass: either way, the power armor becomes stupidly expensive: about 25000$ per kilogram, and I would assume a tank-like power armor weights about 100kg at least. So even if the armor is absolutely necessary, it will be very lightweight, and likely integrated into EVA suits which are necessary anyway. It is extremely unlikely a space station would have tanklike power suits that can stop anything more powerful than a bullet from a civilian firearm.
second frame Challenge: space gun control. It is very unlikely that weapons would be allowed on a station, let alone weapons that can pierce the hull. Sure, this rule will be occasionally broken, but it is far more likely that any kind of space mutinies, piracy, takeovers etc will be done with very low powered weapons 3D printed at the station itself, not military-grade guns.

Having in mind the two above:

very precise laser weapons. Im not talking some silly sci-fi laser blasters, but actual, plausible laser, possibly a laser cutter or a scientific tool repurposed as a weapon. A laser cutter leaves a neat hole, which is very likely to self-weld instantly due to heat, especially in low-oxygen environment (like the surface level of a hull) however, the same hair-thin laser beam will definitely kill, or severely injure a person inside a power suit. A one second blast with steel-cutting laser to the face will melt a neat hole through the power armor helmet, the enemy's head, and the hull, but the holes in the hull will esentially insta-weld back, because you just made a 1mm hole in them, surrounded with molten metal. Human brain though, does not weld back.
drone darts. A space station very likely already needs a whole fleet of tiny drones to whip around like worker bees, repairing the hull, replacing faulty electronics, cleaning etc. Some of these drones will by necessity be equipped with things like laser torches, diamond drills, and other tiny powertools to do their jobs: and they do not care if the job is "fix the wall in cubicle 34" or "drill a hole through powersuit 76 and whoever is inside, Safety Protocol Overriden".
actual hand-held powertools. Sometimes a hull breach is really bad, and you need a heavy plasma torch to mend it. The same plasma torch is usually used to weld damaged power armor. Which means by definition, it must be also able to melt through the same power armor. Any tool that can be used to fix armor can be used to destroy it, if you are brave enough for melee.
pinpoint EMP. The space station itself is most likely ruggedized against EMP 20 times over, evidenced by the fact that everyone on board is not dying after every solar flare or Jovian gust event. Power armor on the other hand is likely not, it would have to be absurdly thick and heavy for that. Just shoot them with a magnetic pellet that stick to their armor and releases a directional EMP blast to fry the suit's electronics, turning power armor into a cool metal statue with a dude trapped inside.
pinpoint radiation blast. Ship hulls are extremely well ruggedized against radiation, evidenced by the fact that the crew is not all dead from radiation poisoning. But if you are fighting for your life anyway, releasing a little bit radiation inside the station is a tiny price for saving your life. A handheld device that blasts someone with a narrow cone of x-rays or gamma radiation (if you are extra, super nasty and want them to die in agony) or microwaves (if you are just regular nasty and want them to suffer unimaginable pain, but survive) will go through armor just fine, and make the enemy regret they attacked you. Come to think of it, radiation guns are so scary that they make space warfare almost obsolete. The very idea of someone hitting you with a single shot of acute radiation sickness that will make you collapse and slowly melt to death in mind-destroying, incomprehensible pain, is enough of a deterrent.
just regular melee weapons. I know it sounds silly, but it is not. Space stations, and moreso spaceships, are made of small, cramped rooms and long, very narrow shafts. If you are fighting against someone there, you are not shooting at each other from hundreds of meters away, but almost at arm's reach, usually across obstacles from all angles. Doors and corners, that is how you get them. Just sneak up on the armored dude, hug them in a jiu-jitsu hold, and stab a screwdriver between their armor joints. If you want to be extra fancy with your melee weapons, Im sure you can 3D print a knife out of monomolecular carbon glass that is sharpened to near-atomic precision and can cut through armor just fine.
shoot them with sealant. A space station already has to have tools that can shoot sealant foam to quickly close hull gaps, and harden fast enough to prevent outgassing. The same foam, if sprayed all over an opponent, will make them immobilized, or at least blinded. With enough foam you can even stick them to the wall and make them trapped. If sealant gun is not available, shooting the opponent with a blast from a fire extinguisher is good enough to blind, distract and possibly throw them back, which can be enough distraction to close into grappling melee.
tasers. Sure, hitting some delicate electronics with a taser is likely going to fry them, but any sensible space station or a spaceship is ruggedized against power surges and has breakers everywhere, so you are unlikely to damage anything more vital than an input panel or a lamp. The same taser applied to a person in metal armor can both cramp them, and possibly fry their power-armor actuators.
tear gas or just straight up nerve gas. Sure, using dangerous chemical sprays on a space station is super dangerous. However, space vessels are designed in such a way that every room, corridor or section can be independently sealed and vented out if needed. If your enemy is in a different compartment from you, blast them with tear gas, or if you really are not playing around, some kind of neurotoxin with a seconds short halflife. Close the door, wait for them to die/pass out, then wait some more for the nasty chemical to decay into a safe form.
finally, your main weapon, if you are in control of the station and attacked by an outside force is "airlock chess". A space station is a maze of airlocked compartments. If you have access to the lock-control system and they do not, you can simply lock them in a room or a corridor and vent the air out, or even open the whole compartment completely to hard vacuum. Sure, most power armor models will have their own emergency air supply, but will it last long enough for them to cut through the airlock? I think not! Even if your enemies are too clever to be vacuumed or spaced like that, you can trap them by surrounding them with vacuumed compartments. If your station is segmented, it might even be possible to detach the whole section where the enemy is, and let it drift off into empty space.


you are making hte same mistake I did, this is not criminals and police it is a full scale military conflict.

@John the problem here of course is that any sensible military conflict at a space station is basically cops vs criminals or quelling a mutiny at worst. You cannot have infantry battles within a space station anymore than naval battles in Liechtenstein: there is not enough room and everything is too fragile and expensive to risk it, you'd blow up the very thing you are trying to conquer. You can either have a power-infantry blasting each other with anti-armor rounds OR a realistically fragile space station but not both.

which would be a good answer.
